# Is there a way to restrict the scroll window of react-calendar-timeline to only visible time start and end?

Tags: reactjs, calendar, visualization, timeline

I am using react-calendar-timeline and there I am using controlled scrolling feature very similar to [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/timeline-demo-controlled-visible-time-no-scroll-659jb?file=/CustomTimeline.jsx). Now as you can see only current date is being displayed but user can scroll the canvas to previous and next date. That means canvas is taking 3x width of the dateRange.
I just need the current date to be displayed in canvas only.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Bumping into this same issue. Found a solution for it?
I have tried to override the `onTimeChange` function to either use fixed visableTimeStart|End values or not even call `updateScrollCanvas` at all, but the items keep scrolling.

Comment: @JoostdenBoer no luck till now. It shows 3x view, one previous and onenext date/months canvas

Comment: I forked the react-calendar-timeline repo and did some modifications myself by restricting the buffer size to 1 when scrolling is disabled (a new property). In the code the size was hardcoded to '3' at 2 places. This seemed to work.
But then I found this fork from [AhmadMHawwash](https://github.com/AhmadMHawwash/react-calendar-timeline) who also made a change to disallow scrolling when the visibleDate[Start|End] properties are set. This also seems to work fine, and is what I am trying out now.

Answer (score 3):

I have also dug a lot over the docs and internet to solve this problem.

Finally, I got it. I am sharing my solution with those who are in the same situation.

Create defaultTimeRange and set to min and max zoom props to disable the zoom.

Then write a handler function for onTimeChange and take the third callback funciton to disable the scroll.

```
// Set the visible start and date somewhere in the beginning like this using useEffect
setVisibleTimeStart(currentDate.startOf("day").valueOf());
setVisibleTimeEnd(currentDate.endOf("day").valueOf());

...

const defaultTimeRange = visibleTimeEnd - visibleTimeStart;

<Timeline
    ...
    minZoom={defaultTimeRange} <--- To disable Zoom
    maxZoom={defaultTimeRange} <--- To disable Zoom
    onTimeChange={(_start, _end, updateScrollCanvas) => {
      updateScrollCanvas( <--- To disable Scroll
        moment(visibleTimeStart).valueOf(),
        moment(visibleTimeEnd).valueOf()
      );
    }}
  >
```

Then you have to override one css class like this

```
.react-calendar-timeline .rct-scroll{
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, the CSS is important!

Answer (score 0):

I have created 3 variables

```
const defaultTimeStart = moment().add(0, 'hour');
const defaultTimeEnd = moment().add(6, 'hour');
const defaultVisableTimeEnd = moment().add(24, 'hour');
```

// create calendar view of one day

```
const defaultTimeRange =defaultTimeStart - defaultVisableTimeEnd;

<Timeline
...
minZoom={defaultTimeRange}
maxZoom={defaultTimeRange}
//it will not allow to scroll more than [enter image description here][1]a day
onTimeChange={(_start, _end, updateScrollCanvas) => {
if (_start > defaultTimeStart && _end < defaultVisableTimeEnd)
updateScrollCanvas(_start, _end);
}}
 />
```